# Do questions about modeling charges in programming fit here?

Tags: discussion

At electronics.SE we received this question: [Representing charges in computer programming](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23761/representing-charges-in-computer-programming)

The gist of the question comes from this paragraph:

> How can electric charges be represented in terms of programming? Do
>   you have to simulate each and every ion or are there overall
>   principles so you can calculate with "whole" charges? I could imagine
>   Circuit simulations already implement some calculations with
>   electrodynamics.

Does this community think it might fit in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much of anything about neuroelectrodynamics specifically, so I can't say for sure, but personally, my first impression is that it would not fit particularly well here. The question seems to be about representing a system in software, which is really more of a programming issue than a physics issue. There's a *chance* it would fit on the beta [scientific computation](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) site, or perhaps on Stack Overflow.

But I would suggest waiting a little while to see if someone with more knowledge in the field chimes in.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it can fit here because there is some physics involved. Most people who run simulations in the bio-physics area use coarse grained models where a complex molecule such as RNA is divided into coarser sub-units based on physical principles. A full molecular dynamics simulation is extremely intensive to perform. The physics comes in when you decide how to coarse grain your model? I am not an expert in the field, but from what little I know, the objective usually is to predict conformational changes or time evolution of structural features. They discuss this as a classical mechanics problem.